# Receiver that can mix inputs?

Tags: audio, amplifiers, mixing-console

I've tried to Google and searching on sites like Amazon, perhaps I don't know the right keywords.

I am looking for a receiver that can mix multiple inputs.  Right now I have a cheap, passive analog stereo mixer, but this does not help me with things like TOSLINK (optical or coax) and HDMI inputs.  It is also an extra piece of hardware, with extra cabling, etc.

Is there such a thing as a receiver that can select multiple inputs at once (mixing)?  Only having the option of selecting one input at a time is not acceptable for my needs.

If this doesn't exist, I'd be willing to run an amplifier with mixing capability, or a separate mixer device--in that order of preference--if it could take multiple input types (as stated above).

Comment: Yes, there is. It's called, strangely enough, a *mixer*.

Comment: You need to identify the type of hardware you need; once you've done that and have some specific requirements for it, this question can be reopened or you can ask a new one.

Comment: I thought I was specific.

Comment: Not particularly, I'm afraid. You also haven't identified the *type* of hardware you're looking for - right now you're asking for a recevier, or an amplifier, or a mixer. We can only recommend one at a time.

Comment: I have edited to specify preference, and acceptable alternatives.

Comment: What is your end goal? I'm trying to think of some sort of solution for you, and I have a few ideas, but it will depend on exactly what you are hoping to achieve. Are you recording? Are you capturing audio for/from video production(s)? Are you mixing for a presentation, or concert of some kind that requires multiple audio ins? In my preliminary search I found [this](http://www.meicheng.com.tw/2009en_html/Cmx-12.html)

Comment: @Steviet Home use, not recording or anything, just mixing inputs to an amplifier which is outputting to wall-mounted speakers (only two--stereo--for now). This became an issue because I want to be able to use the digital (optical) output of my TV instead of analog, and I am forced to use the digital (coax) output of my computer.

Comment: @Heptite Would converting your sources be too big of a pain? It's just that the components you'd need when HDMI and TOSLINK are thrown in the mix either A) require a computer, or B) are ridiculously expensive. Check some of these out and let me know if I'm getting closer or further from your needs. [Here, requires PC](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/HDExpressPCIe). [This is the last ones big brother, needs a PC](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/HDXSDIPCIe) . [This doesn't have TOSLINK, limited inputs](http://www.acekaraoke.com/acesonic-km-201-hdmi-karaoke-mixer.html#.V3VNDNIrLcs)

Comment: @Steviet As this question had been closed for a while, I resorted to converting my PC's digital output to analog with [this](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B005K2TXMO/), but it's not a preferred solution. It's looking like what I really want just doesn't exist, though.

Comment: Good question! People, don't try to be smart. Audio mixing capabilities would be very handy for home use. Besides that it is now easy for manufacturers to implement such feature (as most of them use linux OS).